# Properly edit the location in Calendar events on the Mac

Tags: macos, calendar, ical

It is kind of frustrating what Apple says that about adding a location for Calendar events:

> If you select a location from the list, a map and weather info are added to the event. If you just use the location you entered, map and weather info might not appear.
>
> If the event info window includes a map, an alert is set so you’re notified when to leave to arrive on time at your destination.

So if I use a drop down option but want to add a room number or floor in the building, this event will lose integration with Maps.

---

However, I found a workaround using iOS devices. That is, type the location as you would on iOS Calendar app, then both Mac and iOS will recognize the location, and tell you about weather info, and remind you on the Maps app.

But do you guys have a smarter way?

Answer (score 1):

> But do you guys have a smarter way?

Not to sound flippant, but I use [Outlook App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-outlook/id951937596).  I've used this exact feature extensively (today in fact) where I have to add floor or room numbers and the App doesn't complain.  It still links the Maps data to the event.

The App handles mail and calendar.  It gets [very high reviews](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/v-outlook-for-ios-ipados-new-features-do-not-disturb-split-view-watch-complications-2125236) and some features I now can't do without like the Focused Inbox.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What about on the Mac? I personally do use Outlook for iOS. However, I stopped using Outlook for Mac, because I find I find I'm so comfortable with Focused inbox, that the current Mac version becomes unusable (I know they are bringing Focuses inbox to Mac).